# How to do a ssh from one machine to another machine using Java

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Using putty i am able to do an ssh from one machine to another machine and from there another.Like a chain process.I want to replicate the same in my programme.So far i am able to ssh to the 1st machine.From that machine how do i ssh to the subsequent machines.Also i want to execute some commands like 'pwd' or 'ls' .

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.*;

public class SSH {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

     String user = "******";
     String password = "******";
     String host = "******";
     int port=22;

     String remoteFile="something.txt";

     try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
        System.out.println("connected to first server....");
        InputStream out= null;
        out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
           System.out.println(line);
        br.close();

        /********* Here i want to ssh to another machine from the already connected one ******/

    String command = "pwd" ; //executing correctly with o/p
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    channel.connect();
    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
    while(true){
      while(in.available()>0){
        int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if(i<0)break;
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
      }
      if(channel.isClosed()){
        System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
        break;
      }

    }
    channel.disconnect();

    Channel channel1 = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel1).setCommand("ssh username@hostname" + "&&" + "password");//not    executing
    channel1.setInputStream(null);
    in = channel1.getInputStream();
    channel1.connect();
    channel1.disconnect();



    Channel channel2 = session.openChannel("exec");

    ((ChannelExec) channel2).setCommand("ls"); //to verify if ssh to 2nd machine has happened.not working
     channel2.setInputStream(null);
     in = channel2.getInputStream();
    channel2.connect();
   // byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
    while(true){
      while(in.available()>0){
        int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if(i<0)break;
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
      }
      if(channel.isClosed()){
        System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel2.getExitStatus());
        break;
      }

    }
    channel2.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
     } catch(Exception e) { System.err.print(e); }
   }

}
```

Comment: You will have to SSH into machine 1 and forward machine 2's port 22 onto a local port on your machine. Then ssh into that port, that will get you to machine 2. Rinse and repeat for however many "chains" you need.

Comment: can you please provide any detail on how to change this port to my local port?Also is there any way i can execute linux commands on these machines?I am working from a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

After the session.connect(); use the code to execute the commands in your linux server

```
                            session.connect();
            command = "pwd;" + "ssh username@hostname" + "&&" + "password" ; // u can give your own commands

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i > 0) {

                        output = new String(tmp, 0, i); // name a variable of your own

                    } else {

                        break;

                    }

                    System.out.println(output);

                }}
                                         channel.disconnect(); 
                                         session.disconnect();
```

Make sure you disconnect the channel. So that u can create a new channel and execute your next command.

Comment: Ok so modified the code accordingly.For the 1st command that i am executing i am getting the result i.e for "pwd" but the subsequent commands are not getting executed.I was trying this as an alternative to ssh to the other machine from the current machine.Please check if what i have done is correct.Thanx for the help.

Comment: Please look into my edited code. hope it helps. Just separate the commands by semicolon so that you will be able to run multiple commands.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me. But I'm not sure if this is the correct procedure.

`public class SSH {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server1="server1";
    String server2="server2";
    String user1="user1";
    String user2="user2";
    String password1="pswd1";
    String password2="pswd2";

    String command1="ls -ltr";

    try{

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session1=jsch.getSession(user1, server1, 22);
        session1.setPassword(password1);
        session1.setConfig(config);
        session1.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected session1");



        Session session2=jsch.getSession(user2,server2);
        session2.setPassword(password2);
        session2.setConfig(config);
        session2.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected session2");


        Channel channel=session1.openChannel("exec");   
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);   
        channel.connect();

        Channel channel1=session2.openChannel("exec");  
        ((ChannelExec)channel1).setCommand(command1);
        channel1.setInputStream(null);
        InputStream in1=channel1.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec)channel1).setErrStream(System.err);   
        channel1.connect();

        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        while(true){
            while(in1.available()>0){
                int i=in1.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channel1.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel1.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }

            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session2.disconnect();
        session1.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}`

Comment: but this is to ssh 2 different machines separately but i want to ssh from machine 1 to 2 then from 2 to 3 and also execute some basic commands in any of the machines